# Outlook 2003 Profile needs to prompt for password

Tags: security, exchange, outlook, microsoft-office

In outlook 2003 running on windows xp multiple profiles have been added for tellers. So when outlook starts up its asks the tellers which profile they want to use. for all but one users it then prompts for the password. Which being a bank environment is good. however the one users does not. How Can this be enabled. I went into the users email settings and selected Prompt for password. but that did not work.

Thanks

Comment: Is the one user that doesn't get prompted the logged in user of that machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting and re-creating their profile.

Also does the account the machine is logged in with match that person since those creditentials will get passed though as well.

Answer (score 1):

As LEAT said the passed through credentials cannot be denied, that I have been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

In the profile properties on the Security tab (where the Always prompt for username and password tick box is) try changing the Logon network security to "Password Authentication (NTLM)".

JR